# Convergence of an infinite sum, whose terms are supported in balls, in Besov space

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose we have a ball $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $\alpha >0$, and $\{ u_j\}_{j\geqslant-1} $ is a sequence of smooth functions such that the Fourier transforms $\mathcal{F}(u_j) $ are supported in $2^jB$, and $\lVert u_j\rVert_{L^\infty}\leqslant C2^{-j\alpha}$ for all $j$, where $C$ is a constant independent of $j$. How to show the series $$\sum_{j\geqslant-1}u_j$$ converges in the space of tempered distributions?

Comment: Hans Triebel studied problems of this kind some time ago: I am not sure if this could be of some help to you, but perhaps a look at his monograph *The Structure of Functions* is worth doing, at least for the first chapter.

Answer (score 1):

The following arguments maybe a solution. For any Schwartz function $f\in \mathcal{S}$, we can estimate $$|<u_j,f> |\leqslant \|u_j\|_{L^\infty}\|f\|_{L^1}\leqslant C 2^{-j\alpha}\|f\|_{L^1}$$which concludes that $$<\sum_{j=-1}^{\infty} u_j,f>$$converges.